# Python dynamic GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, dynamic

I want to do a dynamic GUI in Python.
Let's say I have an array of values between 0 and 10.
I would like to have a graphical element that changes its color according to the current value of the array (0-1 is blue, 1-2 is dark blue, 2-3 is yellow, etc. until 9-10 is red).
The goal is to loop on the array and see in real-time the color of the graphical element changing.

Is that doable?
Which GUI would you use?

Answer (score 0):

You can create dictionary that stores all  those values . Later you can use one of the Multiple libraries in Python for plotting : Ex
PyQtGraph , Matplotlib

I found this page that could be useful for you
https://pythonspot.com/en/gui/

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try this !

Comment: If you need more help let me know.If the response was useful, please mark it as useful , or solved , so other can use it in future searches. Thanks